# Explanation of fringe pattern of thin film interference

Tags: optics, classical-mechanics

Recently i went through calculations for finding the path difference between the first 2 reflected rays for a oil film with air on other 2 sides .But i could not understand how the fringes will be observed ,if anyone can draw a ray diagram to explain the pattern of fringes observed ,it will be a great help for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want an image, a particular case are Newton's rings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_rings